# How does an electromagnetic wave detach itself from something rather than fluxing? electromagnmetiac radiaton

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

*how does an electromagnetic wave detach itself from something rather than fluxing? electromagnetic radiaton.*
I need the info for a project and simply couldn't find any useable information on YouTube.
other than that all the info I saw on other websites where different/didn't answer the question I had.

Comment: What do you mean by "fluxing"?

Comment: as far as I know electromagnetic waves flux. meaning that Magnetic flux is a measurement of the total magnetic field which passes through a given area. so that means they don't detach from something

Comment: I know what *flux* means as a noun, but I still don't understand what you mean when you use it as a verb.

Comment: Magnetic flux is a measurement of the total magnetic field that *pierces* a given surface, but that doesn't mean that the magnetic field is *flowing through* the surface. There just *is* a magnetic field *at* the position of the surface, and $\int_S\vec{B}\cdot d\vec{A}$ (roughly speaking) measures the amount of  magnetic field *at* the surface that points perpendicular to the surface.  There is no flow involved.  (You might have seen analogies with fluid flow; the math is the same, but it is not a good *physical* analogy.)

Answer (score 1):

Electrostatic and magnetostatic fields require sources, but electromagnetic waves are self-propogating. This can be shown by comparing two of the four Maxwell equations.

The Maxwell-Faraday equation:

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$$

Ampere's circuital law:

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{B}=\mu_{0}\mathbf{J}+\mu_{0}\epsilon_{0}\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$$

[These can be used to derive two matching wave equations:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation)

$$c^{-2}\frac{\partial^{2}\mathbf{E}}{\partial t^{2}}-\nabla^{2}\mathbf{E}=0$$

and

$$c^{-2}\frac{\partial^{2}\mathbf{B}}{\partial t^{2}}-\nabla^{2}\mathbf{B}=0$$

where

$$c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu_{0}\epsilon_{0}}}$$

---

The above equations then give us two oscillating fields orthogonal to each other, which co-propogate forward along a shared Poynting vector.

[image]

---

While electromagnetic radiation must originate from some source (e.g. an accelerated charge, particle decay, particle anti-particle annihilation, downward electron orbital transition, etc.), since it is self-propogating, the radiation itself is independent from its source.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a good one and the full answer involves some complicated mathematics. But you can get a good feel for the answer by considering the following sequence of events, and sketching field lines.

We imagine a spherical object of uniform positive charge density $\rho$, like a spherical cloud of protons somehow glued into place. We imagine another similar object but now with opposite charge density $-\rho$, such as a cloud of electrons. Start with these two spheres at the same location, exactly overlapping, so the net charge density is everywhere zero and there is no electric or magnetic field.

Ok, now imagine the two spheres first moving apart from one another (by approximately one diameter) and then coming back together. Try sketching the field lines at the moment when the two spheres are just separated. The electric field lines go from the positive to the negative sphere, curving around. There are also magnetic field lines because as the spheres moved apart there was a current. The magnetic field lines go in loops around this current.

Once the spheres come back together (and cease moving) they then generate no further field.

But meanwhile what has happened to the field we sketched? The answer is that it propagates outwards at the speed of light, like a ripple in a pond. To prove that you need the mathematical details which I am omitting. But I can give some general intuition about it.

Imagine an observer who is at distance $L$ from the two spheres. We consider this observer at the moment occuring a time $\Delta t = L/c$ after the two spheres reached their point of maximum separation. Now if the two spheres were to stay separated then I think we must agree such an observer will experience a field from those spheres. But consider: the observer's experience cannot depend on what the spheres will do next (i.e. come back together). So it follows that this observer must observe a non-zero field from the spheres in the actual motion they were undergoing, in which they did subsequently come back together.

This argument, extended to all observers at all locations, is sufficient to establish that the non-zero field from the spheres cannot simply vanish and must propagate outwards at the speed $c$ (or possibly some slower speed, but actually it does move at speed $c$).

Finally, the two spheres example is not as artificial as you might think. It is in fact a good approximation to what happens when atoms emit light. There you have an electron wavefunction moving relative to an atomic nucleus. The electron wavefunction is not always exactly spherical, but it is usually moving between distributions with axial symmetry, oscillating for some (often large) number of cycles with diminishing amplitude until it comes to a halt.

Comment: thank you!! this really helped